# Image grid rows html and css

Tags: html, css, image, gridview

everyone, I'm trying to add a grid of products to my website with description. something [Grid View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRqRz.png) like this? How would I do it? Any help?

Comment: Please try something & show us before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid).

```
<div class="fluid-container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   </div>
</div>
```

[Quick Bootstrap CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked bootstrap to your project?
if you do they have a good and easy to use grid system.

[bootstrap grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>
```